# Ho to Change URL body according to checked box/boxes state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, if-statement

In my **React/JS** project, user checkes one or more of 3 option which user wants to see that type of data . These data types are **final**, **generation**, and **availability**. All of these 3 data types has different url's. I need to send request these data types which are **checked** in the form, I will not send the request to the unchecked one. I need a logic to check which one is selected and which one is unselected. I'm holding these data type states in an array named **datatypes** like this.

```
  {
    "id":"final",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id":"generation",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id":"availability",
    "isChecked": false
  }
]
```

I'm changing the state of isChecked property true, or false. And finally ı need to make a check and send request the **isChecked= true** ones. But ı dont want to do this operation like this:

```
**if**(datatypes[0].isChecked===**true** && datatypes[1].isChecked===**true** && datatypes[0].isChecked===**true**){

//request for 3 of data type

}
**else if**(datatypes[0].isChecked===**true** && datatypes[1].isChecked===**true** && datatypes[0].isChecked===**false**){

//request for first two data type(final, generation) and not for the 3. one 

}
**else if**()...
```

It is exactly not the correct way to make this check. so what is the best and short logic for this situation? I'll be really greatful for every help and advice,
Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're asking about how to filter the list of possibilities into an actionable list of only the checked options. This is basically a filter then map operation as shown below.

```
const possibilities = [
  {
    "id":"final",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id":"generation",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id":"availability",
    "isChecked": false
  }
]

// if you need to do a single request for each checked option
function doMyRequest(option: string) {
  ...your request code here
}
possibilities
  .filter(possibility => possibility.isChecked)
  .forEach(possibility => doMyRequest(possibility));

// or if you need to do one request with all checked options
function doMyRequest(options: string[]) {
  ...your request code here
}

doMyRequest(
  possibilities
    .filter(possibility => possibility.isChecked)
    .map(possibility => possibility.id)
);
```